# Updating nhibernate from 2.1.2.4000 to 4.0.0.4000(with Target .Net FW 3.5)

Tags: asp.net, .net, nhibernate, .net-assembly, updating

Actually, I want to update old 'nhibernate' version used in my ASP .Net project to its latest stable version i.e. 4.0.0.4000.
However, in this process, I am facing problem.

Currently, Target .Net Framework of my project is .Net 3.5 and with that nhibernate 2.1.2.4000 is used.

For updating the same, I have simply replaced the NHibernate.dll assembly with its 4.0.0.4000 version(downloaded from SourceForge).
However, with .Net 3.5 target framework and nhibernate 4.0.0.4000, I am receiving a number of errors related with missing definition of Type/Namespace like Criterion, Engine, SqlCommand, Type, Cfg, Impl, Metadata etc.
Also, on changing Target Framework to .Net 4.0 or higher and nhibernate 4.0.0.4000, almost all the errors gets removed.

So, it seems that nhibernate 4.0.0.4000 is not compatible with .Net 3.5 Framework. Am I correct?
If so, which max version of nhibernate can be used with .Net 3.5 Framework?
If not, please confirm what could possibly causing these errors and how it can be evited.
Also, please confirm the min .Net framework required for using nhibernate 4.0.0.4000. Let me know if there is any other information I needs to be aware of.
Lastly, please confirm if process of updating nhiberate is correct or not?
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Shubham

Comment: The supported .NET versions are 4.5.2 and above. Besides 3.5 just doesn't have features like LINQ that are supported by NH 4.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis ,
Thanks for your response. 
Just to confirm, Which max version of nhibernate can be used with .Net 3.5 Framework? 
Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right: NHibernate 4 only targets .NET 4. You can see that in the release notes: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, Thanks for your response.

Just to confirm,
Which max version of nhibernate can be used with .Net 3.5 Framework?
Please confirm.

Thanks

Comment: It should be the last one of the 3.* branch.